# How to make a cross reference of a figure inside ordered lists?

Tags: cross-referencing

I inserted an image inside an ordered lists like

```
      Plan
      1. Separate the samples 
           (figure 1 )
      2. Clean the samples as shown in (cross-ref of figure 1).
```

I labeled the image as \label{fig:1} and then, I used \ref{fig:1} to make a cross-reference.

But it shows ...as shown in 1 (which is from 1. Separate the sample). 
How do I refer to figure 1 not 1?

Comment: Welcome! Did you add the `\caption` before the `\label` inside the `figure` environment? Please provide a proper minimal document rather than pseudo-code as all we can do right now is guess what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say what's wrong without a minimal example, but the usual code would be something like this:

```
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item\label{enum:something}Something (see \ref{fig:stuff}
        \begin{figure}
          Stuff
          \caption{Stuff}\label{fig:stuff}
        \end{figure}
       \item\label{enum:somethingelse}Something else
    \end{enumerate}
```

Note that `\caption` must come before `\label` in the `figure` environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've simply missed writing 'Figure' before your \ref command. Your code should be:

`Clean the samples as shown in Figure~\ref{fig:1}.`